# django-notification emit_notices extra sql queries?

Tags: python, django

So I've been trying to figure out why django-notification emit_notices prints out multiple extra queries that dont have to do anything with my notices queue

i run in the interpreter:

```
notification.queue([to_user], "new_msg", {"from_user": from_user}, sender=from_user)
```

then

```
python manage.py emit_notices

------------------------------------------------------------------------
acquiring lock...
acquired.
(0.001) SELECT `notification_noticequeuebatch`.`id`, `notification_noticequeuebatch`.`pickled_data` FROM `notification_noticequeuebatch`; args=()
(0.001) SELECT `auth_user`.`id`, `auth_user`.`username`, `auth_user`.`first_name`, `auth_user`.`last_name`, `auth_user`.`email`, `auth_user`.`password`, `auth_user`.`is_staff`, `auth_user`.`is_active`, `auth_user`.`is_superuser`, `auth_user`.`last_login`, `auth_user`.`date_joined` FROM `auth_user` WHERE `auth_user`.`id` = 3 ; args=(3,)
emitting notice new_msg to userTest
(0.000) SELECT `notification_noticetype`.`id`, `notification_noticetype`.`label`, `notification_noticetype`.`display`, `notification_noticetype`.`description`, `notification_noticetype`.`default` FROM `notification_noticetype` WHERE `notification_noticetype`.`label` = new_msg ; args=('new_msg',)
(0.000) SELECT `django_site`.`id`, `django_site`.`domain`, `django_site`.`name` FROM `django_site` WHERE `django_site`.`id` = 1 ; args=(1,)
(0.001) SELECT `cities_city`.`id`, `cities_city`.`name` FROM `cities_city`; args=()
```

And many other extra sql queries (like the last one - select from cities_city ) which dont have anything to do with the notification.queue() written above.

emit_notices calls send_all() and send_all() calls

```
send_now([to_user], label, extra_context, on_site, sender)
```

I dont see the relation with cities which is a totally different app of my project.

However it works, but I wanna figure out why is this happening. Am I doing something wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I bet these queries are generated by the notification template rendering.

Comment: I thought about that too. I removed {{ everything with curly braces }} from the template ... Still getting the queries. If this is what you are saying ..

Comment: what about {% %} ? Remove **everything** from the template to make sure.

Comment: i deleted the damn thing it still sends out the default one .. i truncated the default one from site-packages/djang_notification and the extra queries are still being printed out ... think im gonna go with a fresh install and see how that goes

Comment: You could debug from send_now()

Comment: i created a new project, tested it and worked without the extra queries .. how can i debug from send_now() ?